# Get alternative filename in windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode, filesystems

I'm running my program on windows that will enumerate the files in a directory and pass it on to some other library that processes the files. While my program does support unicode, the library doesn't, so I have to convert the unicode file path and name to ANSI. That works just fine, as long as there are no unicode characters in that filename.

I know that every file  and directory in windows is accessible through it's 8.3 name, but I don't know how to get that name through the windows api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GetShortPathName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx)

It should be noted that shortname generation can be turned off ([fsutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil))

Comment: Correct. Just be aware that this call can fail, if the user has disabled 8.3 generation on the volume. The fsutil command line tool can tell you that.

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT-: Thanks, I was already editing the answer, just had to track down the fsutil link :)

Comment: 8.3 names also have other issues, they are not 100% persistent during copy operations and I guess you could also run out of names (almost like a hash collision)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find. Thank you!